# How do I generate a CHM from existing web pages?

Tags: documentation, chm

There are plenty of great Content Management Systems and Wiki applications that make it a breeze to create & manage web-based product documentation.  These web-based applications also have commenting, social media integration and tools for harnessing the crowd.

All of this web-based technology results in better documentation.

--

So...how do I turn all of this wonderful web content into a CHM that can be browsed offline?

--

I've read about tools that generate web-content from offline files, but that's the reverse process that I'm looking for.  The good stuff lives online in living web documents.  The goal is to take a periodic snapshot of this content and turn it into a CHM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A free way to compile CHM from set of HTML pages is using MS HTML Help Workshop: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms669985
However it's not very handy and requires some skills.

Abee CHM Maker seems to be the cheapest paid tool in the market. It's about $20 per license.

Other tools that may import HTML pages and produce CHM with topic of contents, full text search, indexes are costly (>$100) but flexible: Dr.Explain, Help&Manual, Help Scribble, HelpNDoc, etc.

Comment: Well, but if I need also to create PDF, can I use the MS HTML Help Workshop, or should I try the other products?

Comment: No. MSHW can create only CHM from HTML. To create PDF files from the same source you likely must use a paid tool.